# how to pass input data to another component in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

[this is what i want to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5j44f.png)

If I press the edit button on App.tsx,
I want to display the data in input text in AddToto.tsx.

I would appreciate it if you could tell me what method to use.

this is App.tsx

```
    const App: React.FC = (props) => {
      const [todos, setTodos] = useState<Todo[]>([]);
      const [users, setUsers] = React.useState([] as Voca[]);
   
    
      const editData = (id: number) => {
        const item = users.find((user) => user.id === id);
        console.log(item.word);
      };
    
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <h1>add word</h1>
          <NewTodo onAddTodo={todoAddHandler} />
          <hr />
          <h1>edit word</h1>
          <AddTodo />
          <hr />
          <table>

            {users.map((user, index) => (
              <tr key={index}>
                <td>{user.word}</td>
                <td>{user.meaning}</td>
                <td>{user.enrollmentDate}</td>
                <td>{user.editDate}</td>
                <td className="opration">
                  <button onClick={() => removeData(user.id)}>delete</button>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <button
                    className="btn btn-warning"
                    onClick={() => {
                      editData(user.id);
                    }}
                  >
                    edit
                  </button>{" "}
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </table>
        </div>
      );
    };

export default App;
```

this is AddTodo.tsx

```
class AddTodo extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <div className="form-control">
          <label htmlFor="word">word:</label>
          <input type="text" id="word" />
          <br />
          <label htmlFor="todo-meaning">meaning:</label>
          <input type="text" id="todo-meaning" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">save</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default AddTodo;
```

In this case,
I don't know how to pass data to another component...

Comment: Simple and working: https://therichpost.com/how-to-share-data-between-two-components-in-reactjs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `editData`, once you've found the item, set state which is passed as a prop to `AddTodo`:

```
const [userBeingEdited, setUserBeingEdited] = useState<Voca | null>(null);
const editData = (id: number) => {
    setUserBeingEdited(users.find((user) => user.id === id));
};
return (
    // ...
    <AddTodo userBeingEdited={userBeingEdited} />
```

```
// AddTodo.tsx
export default ({
    userBeingEdited,
}: {
    userBeingEdited: Voca | null,
}) => (
    <form>
        <div className='form-control'>
            <label htmlFor='word'>word:</label>
            <input type='text' id='word' defaultValue={userBeingEdited?.word} />
            <br />
            <label htmlFor='todo-meaning'>meaning:</label>
            <input type='text' id='todo-meaning' defaultValue={userBeingEdited?.meaning} />
        </div>
        <button type='submit'>save</button>
    </form>
);
```

Comment: thanks for your comment! however , I got error in AddTodo.tsx [Cannot find name 'Voca'.] is there any statement that I have to add?

Comment: You referenced Voca in `App.tsx`. Whatever Voca is, you need to make sure `AddTodo` can reference it too so it can be typed properly.

Comment: thanks for your comment! I finally got data from App.tsx !